# how make secure key.properties file in flutter

Tags: flutter

as we write passwords in key.properties file for signing flutter APK. its not dangerous?  how we can make it secure after debugging and reverse engenearing?

```
storePassword=
keyPassword=
keyAlias=
storeFile=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already a secure mechanism that is followed by Android.
Full Article : [Article to refer](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

In Brief:
Creating a keystore file is quite similar as storing configs in environment variables, By default if you generate or sign app using android studio it stores the credentials directly in the gradle file so instead of this when we are working in teams we store these in a different file which is not included when we build and also can be excluded when from source control using `.gitignore`

So we use this keystore variables while signing the app instead of hard coded strings.

Another reason is the .jks file which is indeed really important exists on your pc only and without which you cannot compile the app.

There are practices that you can follow to ensure security like using Proguard and code obfuscation, flutter still is in growing stage so they would likely ensure the use of NDK with which one can write the files natively into .so files, which are much less likely to be decompiled than APKs.

Comment: thx so i use this file and no need to change anything in my app. i dont use git.

Comment: yes, it is a good practice if you do it before publishing to playstore and store the .jks file at a secure place or take a backup

Answer (score 0):

To keep the file private, add it to the `.gitignore` file:

```
**/android/key.properties
```